# How to extract data from hive table to csv using talend

Tags: talend

I want ot transfer data from one hadoop server to another hadoop server with help of Talend.

Through my research I come to know we can transfer data through flat files.Can any one suggest me how to transfer data from hive to flat file. If any other alternative way to transfer data using talend please suggest me.

Comment: Have you checked [this contents of Talend](https://help.talend.com/display/KB/Create+Hive+tables+and+write+data+using+Talend+Hive+components+-+Talend+v5.2+features)?

Comment: Yes i did but i dont find any info

Comment: The video shows a complete use case how to put data into Hive and which components to use how. You can read the data with **tHiveInput**.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the tHiveInput Component to read the data from the hive table. Use a row link to connect it to a tfileInputDelimited component.

If you want to transfer to another Hadoop system, you can use a tHiveOutput or a tHDFSOutput instead of tFileInputDelimited.